# How is this automotive connector supposed to work?

Tags: connector, automotive, crimp

I want to use [this crimp housing](https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/276/1/0643201319_CRIMP_HOUSINGS-172276.pdf):

[image]

The problem is, when connected, there is a gap of about a centimeter between the pins and the crimps. Looking inside, there seem to be only some thin holes in plastic:

[image]

EDIT: Thanks to Andy, I found out that the red plastic is springy and can be pushed few mm. But after doing that, there is only the elastic wire that sticks out and thus, even with pliers, I cannot push the crib any further:

[image]

(A trace left by the pliers can be seen on one of the wires).) Also, the crimp does not click into place.

EDIT 2: I looked around the housing and found a slide which can be pulled out:

[image]

It allows pushing the crimps further. Putting the slide back into the housing blocks them from falling out.

However, it is not easy and one of the wires flexes so much that I cannot fully insert it. Then, this housing supports two sizes of crimps, most of the wires are going to be much thinner and I wonder how would I push them into place.

EDIT 3: I will try to tighten the crimps more, as suggested by JonRB. Maybe the wire insulation is a bit too thick for this housing.

Comment: You might be missing that the crimp and wire push a lot further into the housing than what you initially thought?

Comment: You are right. It turns out, the red plastic is springy and can be pushed further inside.

Comment: But it only moves the crimp few mm, and thus, still no contact.

Comment: Push harder (as they say).

Comment: are you using the correct crimping tool or a pair of pliars?  the thing about these crimps is the ALL the metal has to be formed "correctly" for it to pass through the grommet.  It moves a few mm is expected and now you need to push past it to push through it. This is en environmental grommet  and thus forms a reasonable seal to the wire